# Another Java NIO stumble

Tags: java, nio

Another NIO stumble

I have a small server, which works under Windows and does not work under Red Hat.
The idea is:

- a main thread with a ServerSocketChannel and a Selector
- when it accepts a connection, it creates an Event with the SocketChannel in it
- the Event is offered to the Queue
- each Worker thread has its own Selector an a DB Connection
- the Worker thread takes the Event from the Queue,
  sets the Selector and the DB Connection in it and calls Event's method getProcessed
- the Event reads the SocketChannel (always fine), does something in the DB (always fine) and writes to the SocketChannel (works under Windows and does not work under Red Hat)

the code is:

```
public void processWriting()
throws Exception {
    sk = client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

    String s = "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n" +
    "Location: " + resolution +  "\r\n";

    writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(s.getBytes("US-ASCII"));

    LOGGER.trace("1. limit::" + writeBuffer.limit());
    LOGGER.trace("1. position::" + writeBuffer.position());
    LOGGER.trace("1. remaining::" + writeBuffer.remaining());

    for (;;) {
        selector.select(500);
        // write once
        for (Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                it.hasNext();) {
            SelectionKey key = it.next();
            it.remove();

            if (key.isValid() && key.isWritable()) {
                // write
                client.write(writeBuffer);
            }
        }

        // check all written out
        if (!writeBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
            break;
        }

        // check time
        if (params.getTimeout() < processingTime()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    LOGGER.trace("2. limit::" + writeBuffer.limit());
    LOGGER.trace("2. position::" + writeBuffer.position());
    LOGGER.trace("2. remaining::" + writeBuffer.remaining());

    if (writeBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        throw new Exception("writing failed");
    }
    writeBuffer = null;
}
```

The log output is:

```
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 1. limit::137 
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 1. position::0 
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 1. remaining::137 
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 2. limit::137 
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 2. position::137 
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 2. remaining::0
```

I will appreciate any comments and suggestions.

Comment: how it "does not work under Red Hat"? What is the log output?

Comment: The browser shows "The connection was reset".
Although only twice (out of 50 attempts) I got the correct response - judging by the log - the Opera browser has tried 4 times and eventually has got the response.

Comment: P.S. When it succeeds and when it fails, the log is always perfect:

Comment: 2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 1. limit::137
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 1. position::0
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 1. remaining::137
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 2. limit::137
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 2. position::137
2012-12-20 18:06:13,113 [TRACE] Thread-4:: bg.nalis.pidresolver.Event:: 2. remaining::0